# $arrayElemAt equivalent in MongoDB v3.0

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I want to project array of a document in object form,

```
{
    prop: ['abcd', 'efgh']
}
```

The above one should be projected as

```
{
     first: 'abcd',
     second: 'efgh'
}
```

In aggregation pipeline, [$arrayElemAt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/#arrayelemat-aggregation) can be used like,

```
"$project": {                        
    "first": {                           
        "$arrayElemAt": ["$prop", 0] 
     },                                 
    "second": {                      
        "$arrayElemAt": ["$prop", 1] 
     }                                  
 }
```

This operator introduced in MongoDB v3.2. How can I achieve the same behaviour in MongoDB v3.0? Is it possible to do so? Thanks in advance.